# MongoDB: Performing actions on a field of a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am very new to MongoDB (only got started out of interest last week). I am trying to figure out something and I'm not entirely sure of the terminology to go about searching for it. So I decided to make a SO question.

I created a collection called `Students`. `Students` has the fields `id`, `name`, `undergrad`(which is a boolean), `classes`(which is an array) and `units`(which is 3 times the number of classes the student has).

Now, I wanted to see how I could perform actions on a particular field of `Students`. What I did was, inserted a couple documents and purposefully did not include the `units` field. And I wanted to `$set` the `units` field forEach document/student that did not have the field. I did the following:

```
var studentDoc = db.students.find({units: {$exists:false}})
studentDoc.forEach(function(stu){
  db.student.update({_id:stu._id}, {$set:{units:{$size:"$classes"}}})
 }
)
```

Question 1: Is what I've done even remotely correct?

Question 2: When I type `studentDoc` after setting the `var studentDoc`, it doesn't print anything. But when I write

```
var studentDoc = db.students.find({units:{$exists:false}}).toArray()
```

it prints `studentDoc` as an array but still doesn't seem to do anything in the `forEach` loop.

Question 3: How do I `$set` the `units` field as 3 * (size of classes array)

I hope I have been clear in my question. I have tried searching on the MongoDB docs and google, but haven't had any luck (probably because of my lack of knowledge to search for the correct things).

Any help would be great! You can even point me in the right direction, and that'll be great!

Thank you in advance for all your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why foreach not getting in. You can do the same with below  working code.

```
for(i=0;i<studentDoc.length();i++){
    var stud_id = studentDoc[i]._id;
    var doc = db.students.findOne({"_id":stud_id})["classes"];
    if(doc){
        var len = doc.length;
        db.students.update({"_id":stud_id},{$set:{"units":len*3}})
    }
}
```

As far as I know, You can't use $size:"$" queries in update statement. you will get error like below:

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$size' in 'units.$size' is not valid for storage.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had a couple follow up questions/clarifications, if you dont mind.
1) In your answer studentDoc is not a result of .toArray(), right?
2) Does the use of ["classes"] after a query extract that particular field?
3) I am still confused about when to use quotation marks and when to use $. If you could help me or point me in a direction that explains their uses, that would be great!
Thank you again!

Comment: 1) its not result of toArray(). 2) yes. it will extract classes alone. 3) for functions like set, addToSet, inc. you have to use $. like $set, $inc, $addToSet. these things you'll learn day by day.

Comment: I tried using the code you provided on studentDoc, but I kept getting a ReferenceError: studentDoc is not defined. When I added toArray() to the var studentDoc initialization, the error went away and your code ran perfectly. Do you know why I was getting the error while not using .toArray()?

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [`db.collection.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is cursor.

> In the mongo shell, if the returned cursor is **not** assigned to a variable using the `var` keyword, the cursor is **automatically iterated up** to 20 times to access up to the first 20 documents that match the query. To *iterate manually*, assign the returned cursor to a variable using the `var` keyword. So

```
var studentDoc = db.students.find({units: {$exists:false}})
```

You should iterator `studentDoc` manually.

> Whereas, the [`cursor.toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) returns an array that contains all the documents from a cursor. The method iterates completely the cursor, loading all the documents into RAM and exhausting the cursor. Thus

```
var studentDoc = db.students.find({units:{$exists:false}}).toArray()
```

it prints studentDoc as an array.

If you want to use `forEach`, here is [`cursor.forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/).

```
db.students.find({units:{$exists:false}}).forEach()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var studentDoc = db.students.find({units: {$exists:false}})
```

here studentDoc is a cursor, it's not printable.

you can use forEach

```
studentDoc.forEach(printjson);
```

or iterator the cursor

```
while (studentDoc.hasNext()) {
   printjson(studentDoc.next());
}
```